# Create new derived-class object from List.FindAll

Tags: c#, lambda, generic-list

I have a class called `Myitem` and a derived `List` class `MyItemCollection`...

```
public class MyItemCollection : List<MyItem> { ... }
public class MyItem { ... }
```

I would like to use `FindAll` to return a new instance of the `MyItemCollection` class containing a sub-set of `MyItem` values...

```
public MyItemCollection GetInUse()
{
  return this.FindAll(x => x.InUse);
}
```

However, as the `FindAll` returns `List<MyItem>` and not `MyItemCollection` the above fails.

**Is it possible to get the `.FindAll` to return a `MyItemsCollection` object, or to initiate a `MyItemsCollection` object using the return from `.FindAll`?**

I could do the following, which works, but I'd like to know if there's a better solution...

```
public MyItemCollection GetInUse(bool inUse)
{
  var col = new MyItemsCollection();
  foreach (var item in this.FindAll(x => x.InUse))
    col.Add(item);
  return col;
}
```

Comment: Add a constructor with `IEnumerable` parameter.

Comment: Your alomost *never* want to derive from `List<T>` as you would expose the entire list-interface as well (adding, removing, indexedbased access...). Instead just *use* it, for example as instance-field.

Comment: @Sinatr - yes, I did consider this, but then I'd still need to have a `foreach` loop in the constructor... so seems almost pointless

Comment: @HimBromBeere - *almost never*?  Really?  I use them all the time to provide helpful functionality that needs to be done on the collection itself.  I really would appreciate knowing exactly what you mean, in case I'm really doing things I shouldn't be

Comment: @freefaller No, `List<T>` already has a "copy constructor" so just use that e.g. `public MyItemCollection(IEnumerable<MyItem> collection) : base(collection) { // do whatever else you need to.. }`

Comment: @Johnathan - ah, great point... still means having two constructors when I didn't have any before (one without the `IEnumerable` and one with) but it does work nicely

Comment: @freefaller I'd also heed HimBromBeere's advice; `List<T>`; is better used through composition, as implementing `List<T>` provides a _lot_ of behaviour to consumers. You can always implement `IEnumerable<T>` if you're after LINQ behaviour.

Comment: My point was - as Jonathan mentioned  - you should [favour composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) - not only for `List<T`>, but also other classes. Only expose what you really want to expose. So by deriving from `List<T>` you expose the entire functionality such as adding/removing items from the list. If however you actually just want to expose the index-based functionality, you should have a single member where you provide the index and call `List<T>[index]` instead of exposing the entire list.

Comment: You can do the funtionality on the list anyway, even it is visible only to the internals of your code. However you do so by forwarding the call to **your** api into a call to your internal list.

Comment: Thank you @HimBromBeere and Johnathan - I understand. However, I'm happy for the entire functionality to be exposed, as these list-derived classes are only ever internally used within the software... it's never externally exposed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<T>` has a constructor that takes a `IEnumerable<T>` argument. You can expose a similar constructor in your class, and then do something like this:

```
public MyItemCollection GetInUse() => new MyItemCollection(this.Where(i => i.InUse));
```

Alternatively, don't use your own collection. If you just want to add helper methods on a list, you can use extension methods:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyItem> GetInUse(this IEnumerable<MyItem> e) 
  => e.Where(i => i.InUse);
```

You can also design your classes to have these extended helpers through an interface.  This is handy if you have multiple unrelated classes with similar functionality. The extension methods can then either use the interface as the type argument to `IEnumerable`, or be generic themselves with generic constraints on the type.